# Printing alternate lines using python

Tags: python

I have a text file like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

... and so on.

How do I write a program to print the first 2 lines then skip 3 then print 2 lines (that's the pattern.)

I'm a complete noob.
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Based on line enumeration and assuming a 5-item cycle (display first two items, skip next three items):

```
for i, line in enumerate(file('myfile.txt')):

   if i % 5 in (0, 1):
       print line
```

Comment: I like yours better; its a little cleaner.

Comment: Fine. However, I prefer `i%5 < 2` , and if he wanted lines **0,2,5,6** that couldn't be adapted

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a pattern for this, really. You could just `file.readlines()` the entire thing and use array slicing. If you're concerned about memory consumption, iterate over the file handle using `itertools.compress()` on a pattern generated by `itertools.cycle()`. Or, you know, just write a loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can come up with is to use the modulo operator.  Something like this:

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    if index%5 <= 1:
       print(line)
```

This should produce the pattern you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Since others beat me to the answer here's the one line version:

```
print list(line for lineNum, line in enumerate(open("test.txt", "r")) if lineNum % 5 in (0, 1))
```

:-)

Comment: Impressive, but why is everyone still using python 2.x?

Comment: That's a simple question with a bunch of complex answers.  Personally, I've been working with projects that started before Python3 and don't have the test coverage to just flip the switch and migrate.  I've also quite attached to Twisted and Django which are still quite a ways from their migration.  Anyway, I have no personal objection to Python3 but until more libraries/frameworks get ported and until the language settles down a bit I'm unlikely to be using Python3.  That said, 3.2 is starting to look like a pretty compelling upgrade.  Of course, a number of those goodies are also in py2.7.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print ''.join( f.readline() for i in xrange(7) if i in (0,1,5,6))
```

or

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print ''.join( f.readline() for i in '1100011' if i=='1')
```

or

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print ''.join( i*f.readline() for i in (1,1,0,0,0,1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @pynator's answer, and using the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html),
here is the same solution as a [`ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) - [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) combination.

`z` is an iterable, like `file("myfile.txt")`.
`imap` is used to pick the original data item from an enumerated pair.

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter, imap
>>> result = imap(lambda x: x[1], ifilter(lambda x: x[0]%5 in (0,1), enumerate(z)))
>>> for i in result: print i
... 
line 1
line 2
line 6
line 7
line 11
line 12
line 16
line 17
>>>
```